# FFT-based Image Rotation Algorithms More Accurate Than Chirp-Z?

Tags: algorithms, fourier-analysis, image-processing

We're currently using a Chirp-Z based implementation:

- [R. W. Cox and R. Tong, "Two- and three-dimensional image rotation using the FFT," *IEEE Trans. Image Processing*, vol. 8, no. 9, pp. 1297–1299, Sep. 1999](https://doi.org/10.1109/83.784442)

for rotation of astronomical images. I was wondering if there were any algorithms/implementations out there that could also be used to rotate images using FFTs, and were more accurate than the one we're using now. Perhaps any progress made in the past few years in the area?

Comment: Can you tell me more about rotation of astronomical images?  Around which point should the rotation occur?